# ObjectInputStream doesn't appear to be receiving an ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, server, client

I have the methods:

```
    public void sendTroops(ArrayList<Troops> troops){
    try {
        output.writeObject(troops);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void sendTowers(ArrayList<Tower> towers){
    try {
        output.writeObject(towers);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void sendString(ArrayList<String> str){
    try {
        output.writeObject(str);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Object> receiveObjects(){
    try{
        return (ArrayList<Object>) input.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

used here:

```
private void updateConnection(){
        if(isClientActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                client.sendTowers(towers);
                System.out.println("sent towers: " + towers.size());
            }else{
                client.sendTroops(troops);
                System.out.println("sent troops: " + troops.size());
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = client.receiveObjects();
            System.out.println("obj: " +obj.size());
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troops) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Troops){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }
        }else if(isServerActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                server.sendTowers(towers);
                System.out.println("sent towers: " + towers.size());
            }else{
                server.sendTroops(troops);
                System.out.println("sent troops: " + troops.size());
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = server.receiveObjects();
            System.out.println("obj: " +obj.size());
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troops) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Troops){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to determine that the size of the object array from server/client.receiveObjects(); is always resulting in a array of size zero. I am unsure why this is the issue (as no errors are thrown). Either this is terrible coding practice (which it very well may be) or I'm over looking something.

I would appreciate any help, and if more code/ information of how this program works is needed, please let me know.

Comment: *ArrayList* is Serializable, are your *Troops*, *Tower* Serializable?

Comment: You probably need to investigate `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`.

Comment: @waltersu If they weren't he could not possibly see an ArrayList size of zero.

Comment: yes, they implement Serializable. I'll look into ObjectOutputStream.reset() now

Comment: that may have fixed the issue, but now I have to look into making the class Serializable, as something is causing to not be Serializable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If something isn't Serializable how did you get a zero length ArrayList?

Comment: when I isolate the troop class and socket system away from the game, I'm able to send over the Troop just fine. When I have it in my Game, it sends over the empty array fine, but when I add a troop, it freezes saying not Serializable. I made a new Question, as EJP's comment fixed the immediate issue.